# Simple PowerShell LastWriteTime compare

Tags: file, powershell

I need a PowerShell script that can access a file's properties and discover the *LastWriteTime* property and compare it with the current date and return the date difference.

I have something like this...

```
$writedate = Get-ItemProperty -Path $source -Name LastWriteTime
```

...but I can not cast the *LastWriteTime* to a "DateTime" datatype. It says, "Cannot convert "@{LastWriteTime=...date...}" to "System.DateTime".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try the following.

```
$d = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $source -Name LastWriteTime).lastwritetime
```

This is part of the item property weirdness.  When you run Get-ItemProperty it does not return the value but instead the property.  You have to use one more level of indirection to get to the value.

Comment: Workable, but unnecessarily opaque, verbose, and redundant. See my alternative.

Comment: This worked for me but as brianary pointed out it's a little verbose.  I don't see the reason for the "-Name LastWriteTime" part, and it works without that parameter.  I used this instead:  `[datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $source).LastWriteTime`

Comment: FWIW - The Get-ItemProperty approach on average took 50ms less time than the ls/Get-ChildItem approach for the 200 file comparison tests I ran.

Answer (score 20):

```
(ls $source).LastWriteTime
```

("ls", "dir", or "gci" are the default aliases for Get-ChildItem.)

Answer (score 8):

I have an example I would like to share

```
$File = "C:\Foo.txt"
#retrieves the Systems current Date and Time in a DateTime Format
$today = Get-Date
#subtracts 12 hours from the date to ensure the file has been written to recently
$today = $today.AddHours(-12)
#gets the last time the $file was written in a DateTime Format
$lastWriteTime = (Get-Item $File).LastWriteTime

#If $File doesn't exist we will loop indefinetely until it does exist.
# also loops until the $File that exists was written to in the last twelve hours
while((!(Test-Path $File)) -or ($lastWriteTime -lt $today))
{
    #if a file exists then the write time is wrong so update it
    if (Test-Path $File)
    {
        $lastWriteTime = (Get-Item $File).LastWriteTime
    }
    #Sleep for 5 minutes
    $time = Get-Date
    Write-Host "Sleep" $time
    Start-Sleep -s 300;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`(Get-Item $source).LastWriteTime` is my preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I can't fault any of the answers here for the OP accepted one of them as resolving their problem. However, I found them flawed in one respect. When you output the result of the assignment to the variable, it contains numerous blank lines, not just the sought after answer. Example:

```
PS C:\brh> [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path .\deploy.ps1 -Name LastWriteTime).LastWriteTime

Friday, December 12, 2014 2:33:09 PM



PS C:\brh>
```

I'm a fan of two things in code, succinctness and correctness. brianary has the right of it for succinctness with a tip of the hat to Roger Lipscombe but both miss correctness due to the extra lines in the result. Here's what I think the OP was looking for since it's what got me over the finish line.

```
PS C:\brh> (ls .\deploy.ps1).LastWriteTime.DateTime
Friday, December 12, 2014 2:33:09 PM

PS C:\brh>
```

Note the lack of extra lines, only the one that PowerShell uses to separate prompts. Now this can be assigned to a variable for comparison or, as in my case, stored in a file for reading and comparison in a later session.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly easier - use the `new-timespan` cmdlet, which creates a time interval from the current time.

```
ls | where-object {(new-timespan $_.LastWriteTime).days -ge 1}
```

shows all files not written to today.

Answer (score 2):

Use

ls | % {(get-date) - $_.LastWriteTime }

It can work to retrieve the diff. You can replace `ls` with a single file.